# Создание собственной кнопки Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Здравствуйте,

Использую облачную версию битрикса. Имеется форма в разделе ***CMS -> добавление контактов.***
На неё требуется добавить кастомную кнопку, написав для неё код на PHP. 
Как реализовать кнопку я знаю, а вот как влезть в исходный код и написать что-то кастомное понять не могу.

Возможно ли вообще то, что я хочу сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Есть два способа добавить что то в битрикс24

1. Написать своё приложение для него по типу того что размещаются в маркетплейсе.
2. Сделать бизнес процесс

[Документация по API b24](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/)

Answer (score 0):

Я так полагаю, что используете вы облачную версию не 1C-Bitrix, а Bitrix24?

Для этого веб-приложения вы являетесь внешним пользователем, который хранит там данные и использует функционал. Конечно же, вы не сможете сами ничего написать на php и встроить в какую-то форму.

Ведь, если пользователи могли так делать, то это означало бы полный доступ к системе на уровне веб-сервера -- а там и другие пользователи, и чужие данные...

Конечно, вы можете еще [задать вопрос на форуме](https://forums.bitrix24.ru/forum1/), но ответ будет примерно такой же.

Comment: На форуме меня, к сожалению, игнорируют.
По поводу добавления собственного кода я считал также как и Вы, но меня очень настойчиво убеждают, что это возможно даже в облачной версии.
Через пару часов буду связываться с сертифицированным партнёром битрикса. Предварительно он сказал, что это возможно.

Comment: Вы были правы, добавить или изменить какую-либо форму нельзя.

Собственно моя задача заключается в том, чтобы как-либо добавить в облачную версию кнопку(сказали, что добавить её можно, например, в меню. Кнопка обратится к API другого сайта, после чего отдаст ответ обратно в Bitrix.
Сказали, что можно реализовать это с помощью их собственного API. 
Может у Вас есть какие-то идеи по этому поводу?

Comment: @MaximShinkarev они создадут приложение